# Z3py: how to extend and trunc variables?

Tags: z3

I have two variables 'a' and 'b' of different size, see below. I have few questions:

(1) How can I copy value of 'a' to 'b'? (i.e extend operation)

(2) How can I copy value of 'b' to 'a'? (i.e trunc operation)

Thanks.

```
a = BitVec('a', 1)
b = BitVec('b', 32)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For extending, we use `ZeroExt` or `SignExt`. The `ZeroExt` will add "zeros", and `SignExt` will "copy" the sign bit (i.e., the most significant bit). For truncation we use `Extract`, it can extract any subsequence of bits. Here is a small example (also available online at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/g2bK)).

```py
a = BitVec('a', 1)
b = BitVec('b', 32)
solve(ZeroExt(31, a) == b)
solve(b > 10, Extract(0,0,b) == a)
```

**EDIT**: we can use `p == (x == 1)` to 'assign' a Boolean variable `p` with the value of a Bit-vector `x` of size `1`, and vice-versa. The formula `p == (x == 1)` is just stating that `p` is true if and only if `x` is `1`. Here is an example (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/cGEa))

```py
x = BitVec('x', 1)
p = Bool('p')

solve(p == (x == 1), x == 0)
solve(p == (x == 1), x == 1)
solve(p == (x == 1), Not(p))
solve(p == (x == 1), p)
```

Comment: Leo, your answer is awesome! BTW, how can I 'assign' a variable of Bool type to another variable of BitVec(1) type? This is feasible, given that these two variables are actually of the same size (1 bit size). Thanks.

Comment: The idea of having "p == (x == 1)" is great, but this can only 'assign' value of Boolean 'p', given value of BitVec(1) 'x'. How about doing the opposite: given value of 'p', set the value of 'x'? I tried to use 'Implies', but that is ugly. Do you have a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: hmm it seems i missed the fact that "p == (x == 1)" actually does 2-way operations: given 'p', it also sets the value of 'x', respectively